# how to check if button is active (can be clicked) in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to check whether a button is active (can be clicked ) or not active (exist but not clickable).

I try the following assertions  but it is seems it is wrong. because the first assertion is always true and the second assertion is always false regardless the button is clickable or not.

```
cy.get('#switchdiv').should('not.be.disabled')   //clickable
cy.get('#switchdiv').should('be.disabled')       //not clickable
```

the html code for button in each case:

```
<button role="button" aria-disabled="false" class="styles__CTAButton-eowIhA dBjjkp switchover"></button>


<button disabled="" role="button" aria-disabled="true" class="styles__CTAButton-eowIhA dBjjkp switchover"></button>
```

any help . thank you

Comment: Please share the html of the button in enabled and disabled state.

Comment: @AlapanDas

I share it now

Comment: Could you share the exact button tags you're working with? The ones shared in your  code don't appear to have an 'id' attribute and therefore its relation with the testing code is ambiguous.

Comment: @Waris I edit the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Alapan's answer is not working, you could potentially try and use the `aria-disabled` value.

```js
cy.get('#Button')
  .invoke('attr', 'aria-disabled')
  .then((ariaDisabled) => {
    // Probably helpful to also cy.log() the value
    cy.log(`ariaDisabled is ${ariaDisabled}`);
    if (ariaDisabled !== "true") {
      cy.log('Button exists and is disabled!')
      return
    }
    cy.log('Button exists and is enabled!')
    cy.get('#Button').click();
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('#Button').then(($btn) => {
  if ($btn.is(':disabled')) {
    cy.log('Button exists and is disabled!')
    return
  } else {
    cy.log('Button exists and is enabled!')
    cy.wrap($btn).click()
  }
})
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems still same problem , I try it. this code will always return "Button exists and is enabled!" even though if the button not active.

Comment: I think that might be because the disabled button is an empty string and not `":disabled"`. I'll post an alternate answer in a few moments.